# Issues in clicking element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using java selenium for saving web data if any changes made.

Web page contains two buttons 'Confirm' and 'Cancel'. If i made any changes in web page, both 'confirm' and 'cancel' buttons will be visible at the time i can click confirm button by using below code .

```
WebElement confirm =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Confirm')]")));      
confirm.click();
```

If there is no changes in web page , Confirm button will get disabled(grayed) at the time i want to click Cancel button Automatically.

I have tried with below code ,  it is not working. Please help on this.

```
try
      {
          WebElement confirm = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Confirm')]")));
          confirm.click();
      }    
      catch (ElementNotVisibleException exception)
      {
          WebElement cancel = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]")));

          cancel.click();

      }
```

Comment: Does the code inside your catch block get excecuted? or are you noticing that its not even throwing a ElementNotVisibleException  ?

Comment: are you sure you are catching the right exception?

Comment: @ Moe Ghafari : catch block not executing when confirm button is fails

Comment: @Shank087 : Yes..right exception only

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to complicate things? Keep it simple.

```
 WebElement confirm = driver.findElement(By.id("<your confirm button id>"));
 WebElement cancel= driver.findElement(By.id("<your cancel id>"));
 if(confirm.isEnabled())
  {
   confirm.click();
  }
  else
  {
   cancel.click();
  }
```

You may also try with `confirm.isDisplayed();`

Comment: hi....  Thanks for your response. Button id getting change while executing every time.

Comment: @JegaB .. then just change the locator in this answer to the locator that works for you.

Comment: if it is dynamically changing then use css selector or use xpath (like contains text, starting with) or even find by index.

Comment: @shank087 OP did... he put it in the code in his question.

Comment: oh yea..sorry, I did not notice it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try catching the exception when click on 'Confirm' button fails and as part of exception handling you can click on 'Cancel' button in following way:

```
try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Confirm')]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Confirm')]")).click();
} catch (Exception we) {
    System.out.println("'Confirm' button is not clickable, hence trying to click on 'Cancel' button");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]")).click();
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Confirm')]")));
WebElement confirmButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Confirm')]"));
if (confirmButton.isEnabled())
    confirmButton.click();
else 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]")).click();
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: i have tried as you told, but catch part is not execution when confirm button is fails.

Comment: What exception do you see, when confirm button fails? I have updated the  catch block in my answer. Retry and let me know, whether it works.

Comment: ya have tried with updated code.. getting same result..without showing anything script has ended when confirm button is fails. i think catch block not getting execute.

Comment: when confirm button is enable , at the time try block have executed correctly.

Comment: Please try the code mentioned in UPDATE 1 section of my answer above and let me know whether it works.

Comment: thanks for the update.. have tried, but no change. same result. IF part is executed eventhough condition is failed.

Comment: Else part is not executing even though if condition is fails.

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Confirm')]")));
      WebElement confirmButton = a2.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Confirm')]"));
      if (confirmButton.isEnabled()){
       System.out.println("inside");
          confirmButton.click();
      }
      else 
          a2.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]")).click();      
                   here Syso  getting print in console , when confirm button is disabled.

Comment: Could you share the html for 'Confirm' and 'Cancel' buttons when 'Confirm' button is disabled?